# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest trows invalid URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl

I've got to load a refreshtoken for an API everytime the user opens the app.

In my `appDelegate.m` I'm calling this code everytime the app opens:

```
if(success){ //if the url was successfully retrieved
      _webview=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
      NSString *url=success;
      NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
      NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
      [_webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
      NSLog(@"refreshtoken: %@", success); // logs "website.com/token"
}
```

somehow, however, the webview doesn't load the request. In my `appDelegate.h` I'm creating this property: `@property (nonatomic) UIWebView *webview;`

How come that this does not work?

**update**

As in the answer pointed out, I'm now using

```
`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:nsrequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                 if (error){
                     NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

                  }
                  else{
                      NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
                  }
 }];
`
```

instead of `[_webview loadRequest:nsrequest];`

When logging the error however, I'm getting this response:

```
unsupported URL
```

This is the url that I'm passing:

```
unicmedia.nl/redacted/startredacted.php?userid=redacted&refreshtoken=redacted
```

**update#1**

url didn't start with http:// that's why the error occured.

Comment: Can you run that in a browser?  Maybe use chrome dev tools to look at request and response?

Comment: Yes, it's giving me the correct response. I've only got to open the url with the correct parameters tho, nothing fancy. After it opens it will redirect me to success.php and I can close it again.

Comment: Hmm.. understand that you must redact, but it's tough without see ing the request.  can you NSLog your [url absoluteString], then paste that into browser?

Comment: @danh it's the exact same url.. Can I send you the url in chat?

Comment: @danh http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58575/invalid-nsurl-1001

Comment: Your URL does not start with `http://`. You must include the scheme with the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the idea to do an http request?  In the app delegate, this is better done with an `NSURLConnection`.  The web view being created in the posted code is getting instantly freed (under ARC) as it goes out of scope.  If it's a requirement that you use a web view, keep a strong property to it in your app delegate.

```
NSURLRequest *request = // form your request
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // check error, handle result
}];
```

Comment: that looks smooth! Will try that now.

Comment: Hmm somehow i get an unsupported URL error.. Do you know what that might be?

Comment: please post it.  this might be the first time your code has ever really hit that url (since the web view was getting lost).  another trick is to get the request working in curl (or outside your app).  then it's really easy to recreate in objective-c